# Windows XP suddenly shutdowns slowly after installing new hardware

Tags: windows-xp, performance, shutdown

I've been able to shut down my Windows XP x64 SP2 quite nicely in about 10-15 seconds, but after a "sweet" hardware failure and getting my CPU, motherboard and graphics card replaced and having reinstalled the OS, shutting down takes about 2 minutes.
After clicking Turn Off, my computer seemingly does nothing for said amount of minutes and then finally switches to the usual Logging Off -> Turning off windows routine which takes about 15 seconds.
During these 2 minutes I can still browse my files and open/use some programs, but it will eventually mention something about rundll.exe? or another system file not being able to run, obviously due to Windows trying to shut down.

My old computer parts:
CPU: AMD Athlon X2 6400+
GFX: nVidia GTX8800
Mobo: ASUS M2N

My new/current parts:
CPU: AMD Phenom X4 9950
GFX: nVidia GTX260
Mobo: ASUS M4A78 PRO
RAM: 4GB DDR2 SDRAM (unchanged)

I have also tried: Defragmenting my drives with Smart Defrag, doing a full malware/virus scan with ESET Smart Security 4.0, without any noticeable improvements.

If needed I will upon request conduct more tests.

Answer (score 2):

I've found bad drivers to be the cause of this on numerous occasions. Replacing the hardware would mean you had to install new drivers. You may want to check for more updated ones rather than the ones that came packaged with the hardware on CD.

Comment: I've uninstalled and installed the current latest drivers, problem is still there however.
Not sure if I need to update the chipset drivers since there doesn't seem to be a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to install the updated drivers from the vendors website and let us know if the issue is still persisting ...